# I need help on starting up 12.04 on my computer

Tags: 12.04, grub2, wubi, startup

I have just downloaded 12.04 Windows installer. I managed to boot up 12.04 once but it seems like, after I shutdown the computer, I can no longer access 12.04.

When I boot the computer, it prompts me to **to either boot Windows 7 or Ubuntu**.

I choose Ubuntu, it then starts up but displays a menu, called GRUB I think, prompting me to choose **Ubuntu 12.04** or **Ubuntu 12.04 Recovery**.

When I choose either, it says I have to load the kernel or something all those lines.

I have never used any form of Linux before so I struggle to understand what to do. Please help.

Comment: What is the exact message you get after you chose any of the options in GRUB??

PS - As always, I discourage installation via WUBI.

Answer (score 0):

Michael, 
In my recent dual boots Win 7, Win XP with Ubuntu, Kubuntu Xubuntu, Lubuntu I can only say this: consider the terminal emulator your best friend. It is the highest level portal to install, remove and troubleshoot software/hardware conflicts. It offers the most specific, nuanced installations relative to your PC manufacturer, resident OS, etc. The other gentleman dosen't like Wubi, however it offers some ease of installation. The alternative seems to be a lot of exhausting,complex coding entries. They likely offer better stability when done (correctly) for dual boot OS's on a single disk drive. 
Be that as it may,there are a lot of incredibly helpful people in the Linux community.
If you have Firefox, install the add on ubuntusers. The site is from Germany,and very useful links are mirrored in the states if you do not know German. Skip the forums (IMHO).Go to the "official" sites. Post the blurb about the kernel there. I daresay you will find your solution in short order.It may seem daunting, however the properly executed commands are like a magic key that opens the dungeon door. Even is your system is old, the terminal will rip thru your problem , effecting solutions that are amazing. (Much safer, faster and better than the overrated synapse.
Last, there are nuggets of info. on these sites, e.g., IF ONLY I realized 2 months ago what I learned today-- namely that in Kubuntu (the flavor I've settled on ) the Os gets sensitized to multiple pc's inj the same household who share common DNS DHCP adresses on the same router. It can get to where your pc will refuse to "talk" with another in the same household, fearing some cyberinvasion. Imagine-- built in attitudes for the OS. Some of it is maddening. The BEST workarounds are the "backports" "restricted " packages, and "ppa" portals for software. Though not oficially in the "Cannon" the best and most effective solutions lie there. Solutions involving routers, passwords, security, firewalls, etc -- PROCEED SLOWLY. They can sensitize all those demons that make Linus so blazingly fast. Nothing worse than a pack of angry demons. A lot of water must be applied to cool their jets.

John